# accessing minikube loadbalancer service using VM host ip

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have VM (ip:  10.157.156.176) with linux 7 installed. I am able to access with SSH with VM IP.

I have successfully installed Kubectl, Minikube and created loadbalancer service with 2 pods.

```
[10-157-156-176 ~]$ kubectl get nodes
NAME       STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION
minikube   Ready    control-plane,master   14h   v1.21.2
```

```
[10-157-156-176 ~]$ kubectl get svc
NAME                           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
customers-engagement-service   LoadBalancer   10.106.146.66   <pending>     80:30654/TCP   14h
kubernetes                     ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP        14h
[dc-user@ech-10-157-156-176 ~]$
```

```
[10-157-156-176 ~]$ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP           NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
customers-engagement-service-6f75f4df4b-vlpb8   1/1     Running   0          13h     172.17.0.6   minikube   <none>           <none>
customers-engagement-service-6f75f4df4b-zdjmd   1/1     Running   0          4h22m   172.17.0.5   minikube   <none>           <none>
```

```
[10-157-156-176 ~]$ minikube service customers-engagement-service --url
http://192.168.49.2:30654
```

I am able to access service within my VM (10-157-156-176) using service URL

```
[10-157-156-176 ~]$ curl -v http://192.168.49.2:30654/customers
*   Trying 192.168.49.2:30654...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.49.2 (192.168.49.2) port 30654 (#0)
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200
```

I would like to access the service from different machine (which is having connectivity to host VM) using host VM ip (10.157.156.176) instead of Minikube VM ip (192.168.49.2).

What changes I have to do to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

For type LoadBalancer , you would see that the external IP is in pending state. You need to use `minikube tunnel` to expose it. To use the host IP you need to use nodePort.
Here is a detailed document : https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/

Comment: I have tried tunnel but didn't work as expected. Minikube is running on another VM(192.168.49.2). With tunnel I am still not able to access service using host VM(10.157.156.176).

Comment: Minikube creates a network for itself and the VM. You can use the 'Port Forward a Service' option if you want to externally expose your service. Try using the below command :

service_name=web  # This is what you need to replace with your own service
service_port=$(minikube service $service_name --url | cut -d':' -f3)
ssh -i ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa docker@$(minikube ip) -NL \*:${service_port}:0.0.0.0:${service_port}

(You could also replace the wildcard \* by your machine local IP address).

Comment: For more information refer to the link[https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/877]